# "'Unable to contact any configured publishers' when installing a package on Solaris"

Tags: gcc, installation, solaris

```
# pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                             TYPE     STATUS   URI
solaris                  (preferred)  origin   online   http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/
# 

# pkg install gcc-3
pkg: 0/1 catalogs successfully updated:   
Unable to contact valid package repository
Encountered the following error(s):
Unable to contact any configured publishers.
This is likely a network configuration problem.
Framework stall:
URL: 'http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release'. (happened 4 times)
```

Found the Answer:
It was adding the proxy settings to profile

```
export http_proxy=http://URL:port
```

Comment: I suggest changing the question topic to "'Unable to contact any configured publishers' when installing a package on Solaris".

Answer (score 0):

If you what to use the repository also in the non-globale zone it is better to use the pkg set-publisher --proxy option because the zone pkg proxy does not know your enviroment. Without the proxy option the repository works in globale zone but not in non globale zone.